Java is taking too much memory or misses a few lines when writing to a file
So i have been working on a data extraction schedule that communicates with 3 microsservices to retrieve data from 12 different tables, then writes the data from a table to a file. The problem is i'm having a hard time trying to make the writing part work.
The first iteration of the code was like this:
public <T, DTO> File processPagedDataToFile(
            UUID scheduleUuid,
            Class<DTO> dtoClass,
            BiFunction<UUID, Pageable, Page<T>> findAllByUuidPageable,
            Function<T, DTO> dtoMapper,
            String finalFileName,
            boolean firstPage

    ) throws IOException {
        int pageSize = 2500;

        Path path =  Paths.get(Constants.DIR, "/temporaryFiles", finalFileName);
        String filePath = path.toString();
        Path txtFilePath = Paths.get(filePath);

        Files.createFile(txtFilePath);

        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, pageSize);

        Page<T> pageData;

        do {
            log.info("processing page {} to {}", pageable.getPageNumber(), finalFileName);
            pageData = findAllByUuidPageable.apply(scheduleUuid, pageable);


            try(BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardOpenOption.APPEND)) {
                converterDataToCsvHelper.convertDataToCsvPaginated(pageData.getContent().stream()
                    .map(dtoMapper)
                    .toList(), dtoClass, new BiFileSchema(), firstPage, writer);
            }
            firstPage = false;
            pageable = pageable.next();

        } while (pageData.hasNext());

        return txtFilePath.toFile();
    }

but it took too much memory because of the entityManager holding all the context from the pageable search.
My current iteration is now using entityManager so i can call entityManager.clear() to free the memory.
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public <T, DTO> File processPagedDataToFilePageable(
            UUID scheduleUuid,
            Class<DTO> dtoClass,
            BiFunction<UUID, Pageable, Page<T>> findAllByUuid,
            Function<T, DTO> dtoMapper,
            String finalFileName,
            boolean firstPage
    ) throws IOException {
        int pageSize = biProperties.getFilePageSize();
        int[] processedCount = {0};

        Path path = Paths.get(Constants.DIR, "/temporaryFiles", finalFileName);
        String filePath = path.toString();
        Path txtFilePath = Paths.get(filePath);

        Files.createFile(txtFilePath);

        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, pageSize);
        Page<T> pageData = findAllByUuid.apply(scheduleUuid, pageable);

        final boolean[] isFirstPage = {firstPage};

        try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path)) {
            while (pageData.hasContent()) {
                             converterDataToCsvHelper.convertDataToCsvPaginated(pageData.getContent()
.stream()
.map(dtoMapper)
.toList(),
                        dtoClass,
                        new BiFileSchema(),
                        isFirstPage[0],
                        writer);
                writer.flush();

                if (isFirstPage[0]) {
                    isFirstPage[0] = false;
                }

                processedCount[0]++;

                if (processedCount[0] == 4) {
                    entityManager.clear();
                    processedCount[0] = 0;
                }

                pageable = pageable.next();
                pageData = findAllByUuid.apply(scheduleUuid, pageable);
            }
        }
        entityManager.clear();

        return txtFilePath.toFile();
    }

It works well when it comes to handling the memory problem, but now i have a new problem: when writing the data to a file sometimes it skips a few lines. SO far i have tried adding the flush() method and moving the bufferedWriter try-with-resources to inside the loop, but nothing works.
Also, here's the convertDataToCsv code:
public <T> void convertDataToCsvPaginated(
            final List<T> data,
            final Class<T> clazz,
            final FileSchema schemeFile,
            final boolean withHeader,
            final Writer writer) throws IOException {

        final var csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
        csvMapper.disable(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY);

        CsvSchema schema = csvMapper.schemaFor(clazz)
                .withoutQuoteChar()
                .withUseHeader(withHeader)
                .withArrayElementSeparator(schemeFile.getArrayElementSeparator())
                .withColumnSeparator(schemeFile.getColumnSeparator());

        csvMapper.writer(schema).writeValues(writer).writeAll(data).flush();

    }

I've created a side project just to test this file writing with nothing but the table filled with data (2 million lines) and the processPagedDataToFile method. It works perfectly there and never misses a line. The main project though misses a few, even to a table with 153 entries! Also, there is some parallelism because there are 12 scheduled jobs that uses this method. What is weird to me though is that a table with so little entries (153 lines) calls this method first and still misses some lines when writing the data to the file while the other schedules are still getting the data from the other microsservices.
A snippet calling the processPagedDataToFile if you want to run:
public void createFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        String finalFileName = fileName
                .concat(dateFormat.format(new Date()))
                .concat(TXT_EXTENSION);

        File file = convertDataToCsv(finalFileName);

        log.info("File created with succes with name: {}", file.getName());

    }

private File convertDataToCsv(String finalFileName, UUID uuid) throws IOException {

    return pagingService.processPagedDataToFile(
            uuid,
            DeviceBiDTO.class,
            this::findAllByManufacturer,
            DeviceBiDTO::of,
            finalFileName,
            true);
}

change the BiFunction line to BiFunction<String, Pageable, Page<T>> findAllByManufacturer,

And the object class:
@Data
@Builder
public class DeviceBiDTO {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String deviceId;
    private String deviceModel;
    private String manufacturer;

    public static DeviceBiDTO of(DeviceSchedule device) {
        return DeviceBiDTO.builder()
                .deviceId(device.getIdDevice())
                .deviceModel(device.getDeviceModel())
                .manufacturer(device.getManufacturer())
                .build();
    }


Are you sure that there is a bona fide problem here?  Could it be, for instance, that sometimes the database is updated while you are writing the file, or soon after, so that the file is out of date by the time you check it?

"Also, there is some parallelism because there are 12 scheduled jobs that uses this method" - my neck hairs are standing up reading that. A batch job which is run multiple times in parallel? I can't imagine you wrote unit tests to test if that works as expected. What happens when you run only one job?

"Java is taking too much memory or misses a few lines when writing to a file" those look to be two completely different problems. Questions should focus in one issue.

There are several weird things you should clean up first. 1) Path path = Paths.get(Constants.DIR, "/temporaryFiles", finalFileName); Why is there a / in the second argument? Is this supposed to have an effect or are any effects of a potential file separator unintended? 2) String filePath = path.toString(); Path txtFilePath = Paths.get(filePath); What is the purpose of this conversion? It should have no effect but if it has, it would be even worse.


Files.createFile(txtFilePath); This is obsolete Files.newBufferedWriter(path) will create the file if it doesn’t exist. Use StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW if you want to enforce that the file does not exist before that operation. 4) int[] processedCount = { 0 }; and final boolean[] isFirstPage = { firstPage }; There is no reason to use arrays here. Use straight-forward variables, i.e. int processedCount = 0; and boolean isFirstPage = firstPage;


Note further that of Files.createFile(txtFilePath); contradicts having a parameter boolean firstPage, as the latter suggests that this method might be called to append to an existing file rather. Your memory problem might be better addressed by avoiding pageData.getContent().stream() .map(dtoMapper) .toList() and using a version that converts the elements on-the-fly rather than all at once before the writing. This requires converterDataToCsvHelper.convertDataToCsvPaginated(…) to take an Iterable rather than a List or having an alternative taking a Stream in the first place.

@Gimby It's actually a schedule for each job, all of them controlled by crons! So even though they can run when scheduled, it was specified to run at the same time. And for what happens when running only one: It goes fine and doesn't miss a single line when writing to file, but it fails when running more than one at once, im assuming it's the entityManager.clear()...

@JohnBollinger I'm sure it's not that, each schedule fills a different table and it only starts to write to file after getting all the expected data. Though it runs fine when only one schedule is running, some lines can go missing if there's more than one running in parallel, regardless of if it's still getting the data or writing to file too

@Holger Woah, thanks for the advice! I've cleaned up all the mess you've mentioned! For the pageData.getContent().stream() .map(dtoMapper) .toList() usage though, i've even tried to run it without the mapping and convertDataToCsv call, just getting the data and writing each record into the file and the memory usage would keep the same, even getting the data with stream and writing. It seems that nothing works without cleaning the entity manager persistence, but that too makes some lines go missing when more than one schedule is running

If the issue only happens when you run multiple jobs concurrently, then maybe don't do that?

Anyway, if concurrent independent jobs conflict in some way, then that's probably not an issue that we can identify or solve by looking at your Java code.  You might consider looking at the relevant system logs for clues about what may be happening.

Since entityManager is not in scope of this method, I’m not surprised that calling clear() in one execution has an impact on other concurrent executions. I would try John Bollinger’s suggestion of not executing the code concurrently. Since all target files seem to be on the same device, there is little to gain by concurrent write operations. While memory demands may raise unpredictably when you don’t limit the number of operations running at the same time.
